# Rails4 : How to change the output display page by page with helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

\views\articles\ _article.html.erb is called from \views\categories\show.html.erb and \view\users\show.html.erb.

I don't want to display some contents in \views\categories\show.html.erb.

How do I edit the code?

\views\articles\ _article.html.erb

```
<li>
    <% article.photos.each do |photo| %>
.
.
.
        <aside class="span7">
          <p><%= article.category.code %> | <%= article.category.name %></p> #I don't want to display this line in \categories\show.html.erb
.
.
.
        </aside>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

\categories\show.html.erb

```
.
.
.
<%= render @articles %>
.
.
.
```

\users\show.html.erb

```
.
.
.
<%= render @articles %>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@RajarshiDas` suggested *if your partial **has a lot of different code depending on controller then you should avoid using same partial** but if it's only a minor change then i think it'll be ok*

*Since you are using rails 4 you can simply use rails [**`controller_name`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class) and [**`action_name`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters) helpers.* So in your partial you can simply have

```
<li>
  <% article.photos.each do |photo| %>
    .
    .
    .
    <% if controller_name == "categories" %> // since your action name is same in both case so you only need to check controller name
      <aside class="span7">
        <p><%= article.category.code %> | <%= article.category.name %></p> #I don't want to display this line in \categories\show.html.erb
      .
      .
      .
      </aside>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide some content inside partial, there is a one silly method: You can pass local variable in partial, and use it inside to hide or show something.

In categories/show:

```
render partial: 'article', locals: { hide_category_code: true }
```

In users/show:

```
render partial: 'article'
```

**_article.html.erb**

```
<% unless hide_category_code %>
  <p><%= article.category.code %> | <%= article.category.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

For me, it's better to create two partials. I think that `if` logic is not appropriate for most operations in view.

Answer (score 0):

In simple you can do this

although it is not good ratice

```
<li>
   <% article.photos.each do |photo| %>

         <aside class="span7">
             <% unless controller.controller_name == "categories" && controller.action_name == "show"  %>
             <p><%= article.category.code %> | <%= article.category.name %></p> 
            <% end %>


      </aside>
   <% end %>
 </li>
```

Please refer http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class

or another way

```
  <% unless current_page?(url_for(:controller => 'categories', :action => 'show')) %>

     <p><%= article.category.code %> | <%= article.category.name %></p>

  <% end %>
```

but better way you can optimize the `render` calling do not call this `partial` in `/app/views/categories/show.html.erb` as you did `<%= render @article%>` as it will call this file.

So in `/app/views/categories/show.html.erb` you should call `<%=render 'article/article_category'%>`

and in `app/views/articles/_article_category.html.erb` you should not use the code

It means make a separate partial for `/app/views/categories/show.html.erb`

Comment: In rails 4 you can use controller_name and action_name helpers and also since only controller name is different so don't have to check for action

Answer (score 0):

**Partials**

Here is the [Rails definition of `partials`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

> Partial templates - usually just called "partials" - are another
>   device for breaking the rendering process into more manageable chunks.
>   With a partial, you can move the code for rendering a particular piece
>   of a response to its own file.

The bottom line is that "partials" are meant to be stand-alone ["modular"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming), which means that if you're calling them from multiple actions, you'll be better putting the logic inside the partial to ensure they are displayed correctly.

The problem you're alluding to is how to change the partial depending on how you're loading the application. The way to do this is either to set a variable outside of the `partial` load scope (IE set a "local" variable), or to set some conditions inside the partial itself:

--

**Fix**

I would personally do this:

```
#app/views/articles/_article.html.erb
...
<%= "#{article.category.code} | #{article.category.name}" unless controller_name == "categories" %>
```

Alternatively, you could use a local like so:

```
#app/views/articles/show.html.erb
<%= render @article, locals: {show_category: true} %>

#app/views/articles/_article.html.erb
<%= "#{article.category.code} | #{article.category.name}" if show_category %>
```